# Dockerfile and npm prune --production

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-modules

When I am building a docker image with command `docker-compose build` I saw one unexpected thing.
When a `Dockerfile` has only one `RUN` command

[image]
then the image size is getting reduce.

When we split it to each separate `RUN`

[image]

then the image is not removing `devDependencies` ( around 70MB ).

Can someone explain why is it happening?

Comment: I think that issue arises from *cache*. If you build the Dockerfile with the same tag twice, the command won't run because of the cached built that stored in the docker system.

Comment: I was doing docker system prune :(

Comment: You say "the image size is reduced" but then put two fairly large images in the question.  Did you mean to a copy of your Dockerfile instead?

Answer (score 4):

Because the Docker image has [layers](https://medium.com/@jessgreb01/digging-into-docker-layers-c22f948ed612), and each RUN command creates a new layer that is a diff of the previous layer.

You can use a [multi-stage Docker build](https://codefresh.io/docker-tutorial/node_docker_multistage/) to accomplish what you want.